# Were Lakshmi and Saraswati sisters of Ganesha and Kartikeya?

Tags: ganesha, lakshmi, kartikeya, saraswati

Some people say that both Goddess Lakshmi and Goddess Saraswati are sisters of Lord Shiva's sons Ganesha and Kartikeya. Is this true or false?

Answer (score 1):

> Sarasvati is the consort of Brahma, the Creator, and goddess of the arts, music, learning, knowledge and culture. Her name is a contraction of "Saram vati iti" or "She who flows towards the Infinite". She is the symbol of fertility and prosperity, of purity and creativity, and of literary and verbal skills. She holds a mala, rosary, and a scroll which symbolize her knowledge. **She is a daughter of Durga and sister to Lakshmi, Ganesha and Kartikeya.** Her own children are the four Vedas, the oldest of India's sacred texts. Some say that she was born of Gauri, a personification of Sati; and of the divine Prakrti who gives form to everything at the bidding of Brahma, the Creator. In association with Indra, king of the gods, Sarasvati destroyed the serpent Vritrasura who had hidden and hoarded away all the Earth's waters. She is therefore the destroyer of chaos, darkness and drought. She is the guardian of thoughts and the chief bestower of the light of consciousness that bestows revelation and understanding.

[Link for the above Quote](http://www.sacredthread.net/information/goddesses.php)

Answer (score 0):

They are neither daughters nor sisters. They are three different forms of the same mother (very well described in Sri Durga Saptashati/ Srimad Devi Bhagwatam)

Comment: Sri Lakshmi adopted Sri Ganesha as her son.